# Using SQLAlchemy, how to copy a database of three tables over to my local MySQL database? What are the proper sequence of method calls?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I want to make an exact copy (migration) from this online database:
https://relational.fit.cvut.cz/dataset/ConsumerExpenditures

and copy the tables and data inside of these tables over to my local MySQL database.

I have researched SQLAlchemy but with the jumble of reflection, metadata etc. I am confused as to the proper sequence of calls to copy these tables (see last part of the code block).  Can anyone please let me know the proper way to do this?

Here is my code so far:

`    try:

```
    # Read tables from database and copy over to local MySQL

    srcEngine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mariadb+mariadbconnector://guest:relational@relational.fit.cvut.cz:3306/ConsumerExpenditures")
    conn = srcEngine.connect()
    meta = MetaData()
    meta.reflect(bind=srcEngine)
    meta.tables.keys()  # here I see the three tables in this database


    # connect to local database
    database_uri = 'mysql+pymysql://root:1234@localhost:3306'
    localEngine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(database_uri)

    try:
        with localEngine.connect() as conn_local:

            # create ConsumerExpenditures database if not exists else start copying over tables
            database = 'ConsumerExpenditures'
            result = conn_local.execute(text("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {0} ".format(database)))
            
            # below I am trying to get the metadata from the srcEngine and somehow copy its tables and data over to the localEngine database that was just created.  I am sure of the syntax to do this?
            meta = MetaData()
            messages = Table('EXPENDITURES', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=srcEngine)  # tried to create a table based on the meta data from the source engine but is throwing an error.  What is the call(s) I should make to copy it over?
```

`

Comment: If you want to copy the data you will need to select it from the source tables and insert it into the destination tables.  Metadata & Table will only create the schema.  [Clint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7879634/clint)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75467264/5320906) is going to be simpler and likely more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a regular MySql DB or MariaDb, in my experience (not being a massive fan of python), when copying a database to another server use MYSQLDUMP command to export then MYSQL command to import.

Export

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p [database_name] > [filename].sql
```

Import/restore

```
mysql -u [user] -p [database_name] < [filename].sql
```

You should be able to execute this with Python using subprocess or system see;-
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html
or
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html?highlight=system#os.system

Alternatively use a tool like PHPMYADMIN or MYSQLworkbench.

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically using python ?

Answer (score 0):

As Clint mentioned, you can use Python's `subprocess` module to do this. Here is an example:

```py
import subprocess

def dump_remote_database(config):
    sql_file_path = "remote_db_dump.sql"
    params = [
        "mysqldump",
        f"--user={config.SOURCE_DB_USER}",
        f"--password={config.SOURCE_DB_PASSWORD}",
        f"--host={config.SOURCE_DB_HOST}",
        f"--result-file={sql_file_path}",
        config.SOURCE_DB_NAME,
    ]

    result = subprocess.run(params)
```

My particular situation has some complications in which I sometimes also use the options `--no-create-info` or `--no-data` depending on what exactly I need from the source database (sometimes I just need the data, other times just the table structure).

Similarly, to load the database, you can do something like this:

```py
import subprocess

def seed_target_database(config):
    sql_file_path = "remote_db_dump.sql"
    params = [
        "mysql",
        f"--user={config.TARGET_DB_USER}",
        f"--password={config.TARGET_DB_PASSWORD}",
        f"--host={config.TARGET_DB_HOST}",
        "--protocol=tcp",
        config.TARGET_DB_NAME,
    ]

    try:
        with open(sql_file_path) as f:
            result = subprocess.run(params, stdin=f)
```

In case you're curious or it matters, my application uses Flask, Flask-Migrate, and SQLAlchemy with a MySQL database.

I happened upon this question because I am trying *not* to use `mysql` to load the data since it does not seem to be available in all of the environments in which I need it. Thus, I'm looking for a SQLAlchemy way to do it.